# How do I show a message depending if the value of a dropdown select box is 2 or higher?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I have a fiddle here of my dropdown box, styled with Select2:

http://jsfiddle.net/f6gg37en/1/

```
<select id="quantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<span class="message">You selected 2 or more!</span>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that a message shows if somebody selects the value "2" or higher, but the message should be hidden if "1" is selected. How would I achieve this with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#quantity').change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $('#quantity').find(":selected").text();
        if ( selectedValue == '1' ) {
            $('.message').hide();
        } else {
            $('.message').show();
        }
    });
});
```

to hide/show the message when the user changes the select box value.

**Explanation**:

- when the user selects an option from the select box, there will be called a change function
- the selected option will be stored as string in `selectedValue`
- if that value is '1'

  - the message will be hidden
- otherwise

  - the message will be shown

P.S.: This is enough in your case, but if you want to compare the values as numbers, you can use something like this:

```
var selectedValueAsNumber = parseInt(selectedValue);
if ( selectedValueAsNumber < 2 ) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```